# Wordpress is displaying the thumbnails incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress

For all the pics I upload to Wordpress I get such a link to the pic:

```
src='http://myblog.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/thumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/2012/06/mypic.jpg&w=100&h=100&zc=1&q=90'
```

Anf ofcourse Wordpress does not find it.

But if I change to with the firebug:

```
src='http://myblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/mypic.jpg'
```

Wordpress displays the picture. Where I should look for the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Whichever theme you are using has an image resizer - it is this that is breaking, not Wordpress. What theme is it?

Comment: I use canvas by woothemes. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Might be worth asking WooThemes, who I think give support

Comment: http://www.woothemes.com/tutorials/troubleshooting-image-resizer-thumbphp/